# Default date format of Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo date picker which is set to format date as "**MM/dd/yyyy**". I want to check using jquery/javascript that if kendo date picker date must not be future date and date must be greater than '01/01/1900'.

The issue I am facing is when I take new date in script, it is like `Date {Tue Jun 10 2014 11:17:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}`. and my kendo date picker has value in `06/02/2012` format. I don't know how to compare it.

I know a method in kendo date picker named: parseFormats in which I have to give parsing format, but I don't know defualt date format of Javascript/Jquery and I don't know how to do it.

**Kendo Date Picker**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.DateOfBirth).Format("MM/dd/yyyy").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", Placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" }).Max(DateTime.Now.Date).Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 2).Date))
```

Comment: Similar question here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245661/moment-js-date-comparison-catching-min-range/29245934#29245934  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the toString value of the new Date. Try this

```
var d = new Date(datepicker.value()); // looked at the docs, no obvious shortcut
if (d.getFullYear()<1900) alert("nope");
```

or

```
var now = new Date(), d = new Date(datepicker.value());
now.setHours(0,0,0,0); // normalise
if (d.getTime() > now.getTime()) alert("Please no future dates");
```

More information about JS Dates: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

You can also make it harder to select the invalid dates

```
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
  value:new Date(),
  min: new Date(1900,0,1), // JS months are 0 based!
  max: new Date()
});
```

And lastly add the validation

```
$("#MyForm").kendoValidator({
  rules: {
    //implement your custom date validation
    dateValidation: function (dateField) {
        var currentDate = Date.parse($(dateField).val());
        //Check if Date parse is successful
        if (!currentDate) {
            return false;
        }

        var now = new Date(), then=new Date(1900,0,1),d = new Date($(dateField).val());
        now.setHours(0,0,0,0); // normalise
        return d.getTime() >= then.getTime() && d.getTime() < now.getTime()  
    }
  },
  messages: {
    //Define your custom validation massages
    required: "Date is required message",
    dateValidation: "Invalid date message"
  }
});
```

Comment: wht abt future date validation?

Comment: @Dhwani you can check like if `(d.getFullYear()>getdate().getFullYear())`

Comment: @mplungjan I have a confusion about how .getTime works?

Comment: It gets the milliseconds since EPOCH (1/1/1970) of the date object after applying timezone corrections

Answer (score 0):

Default Date Format of Javascript is MM/DD/YYYY

For Reference Follow [Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 0):

I would pretty much ignore Kendo's methods altogether and use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in a validation function when you submit.  You can format each date, min, max, and candidate, as YYYY-MM-DD, then compare using built-in `.isAfter()` and `.diff()` [queries](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).  Remember that you have to account for if they type something, not just pick it from the calendar, so you have to ensure you have 2-digit days.   You also have to account for if someone enters in something outrageous that is higher than the Kendo control can deal with, like 1/1/0001 and 1/1/9000.  Code below deals with that.  You may also - though I did not include it here in my code, but did in my fiddle - want to account for if the year is only 2-digits, as well:

```
$('#btnValidate').click(function(){
     var minDate = moment('1900-1-1');
     var maxDate = moment(Date.parse(new Date()));

     //var dateField = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
     var dateField = $("#datepicker").val();

     // Moment requires YYYY-MM-DD
     dateField = dateField.replace('/','-').replace('/','-');
     var year = dateField.split('-')[2];
     var month = dateField.split('-')[0];
     var day = dateField.split('-')[1];

     if (month < 10 && month.toString().length == 1) { month = "0" + month; }
     if (day < 10 && day.toString().length == 1) { day = "0" + day; }
     dateField = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

     // Enter into moment and compare
     var dateToConsider = moment(dateField);
     var lowerLimitBreached = dateToConsider.diff(minDate) < 0;
     var upperBoundBreached = dateToConsider.isAfter(maxDate);

     alert('min: ' + moment(minDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
     alert('max: ' + moment(maxDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
     alert('our candidate: ' + moment(dateToConsider).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

     if(lowerLimitBreached || upperBoundBreached)
         alert('Invalid date');
     else
         alert('Valid date');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/k5xx9xpu/

Note that the example doesn't show using times, but you could add that if you got the time from the `.data("kendoDatePicker").value` commented-out line.  I just would not trust the year since "0001" will translate as "1901".  So I would say that appending the time to the `dateField` object would be the way to go, and you can hard-code the time on it like `moment(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs + 'Z').utc()` and the min like `moment('1900-1-1T00:00:00Z')`, though `00:00:00Z` is already implied if you do not set it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use KendoUI's datepicker method as shown below:

```
  var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
  var value = datepicker.value();
```

Here value will be holding value like `Tue Oct 11 2015 11:17:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Now you can use simple condition to compare values

**EDIT**

You can refer demo at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/9A2uG/2/)

Once you have javascript date format you can use condition to compare dates, as I have in demo code

Comment: Likely the datepicker value is 06/02/2012 whereas Dhwani is using new Date() and does not realise he is getting the toString of it

Comment: @mplungjan Could you please elaborate. I am not able to get you

Comment: Your code is not working correctly. Your date is 1900/02/01 and not 1900/01/01 since JS months are 0 based. Also the date picker will return a null if you type a date < the allowed date - see http://jsfiddle.net/tJ6EB/

Comment: @mplungjan that is understood whether is 1900/02/01 or 1900/01/01, we are trying to help for reference code and not to deliver perfect code.

Comment: I disagree. If a beginner gets reference code that is faulty, they will get very confused. Please try to deliver as perfect code as possible.

Comment: @ChiragVidani Your fiddle says 01/01/0001 is a valid date.  I created a fork of your fiddle to show a better way to validate:  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/k5xx9xpu/