# Moment.js - Date comparison: Catching min range

Tags: jquery, validation, date, momentjs, kendo-datepicker

My form has a Kendo DatePicker and a button that runs a JavaScript function prior to doing a form.submit().  I need to be able to compare my date that is entered against a lower limit, and prevent the code from going on (submitting the form) if it is earlier than my set date.  I want to return false if the limit hasn't been breached, true if it has.  I'll use this example to show what I'm trying to do in the validation code:

```
var lowerBound = new Date('1776', '6','4');  // July 4, 1776
var dateField = $('#myDateField').val();  // <-- comes from Kendo DatePicker
var dateToConsider = new Date(dateField);  // if this is 1/1/0001, this changes to 1/1/1901... not good, so I do this, instead....

var arrDate = dateField.split('/'); // I also check for '-', ' ', and '.'
dateToConsider = arrDate[2] + '-' + arrDate[0] + '-' arrDate[1]; // could add 'T00:00:00Z'; but don't think it matters

var momentDTC = moment(dateToConsider);
var lowerLimitBreached = moment(lowerBound).isAfter(momentDTC); // <-- this is always false

if (!lowerLimitBreached)
    $('form').submit();
```

I've been inputting 1/1/0001 into the control, and it keeps giving `lowerLimitBreached` as false, when it should be true, since 1-1-0001 is clearly earlier than 7-4-1776...  I tried using `.isBefore()`, but met with the same issue, and the documentation actually says `NOTE: moment().isBefore() has undefined behavior and should not be used!`, so I dare not use that.

Moment documentation:  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using moment.js, don't use the JavaScript Date object at all. Stick to moment objects only.

```
//evaluates correctly
moment('0001-01-01');

//evaluates to Feb 2, 0001 - makes no sense...
new Date(Date.parse('0001-02-03'))
                            //^ but that's a 3, not a 2

//true - Jan 1, 0001 is before June 4, 1776
moment('0001-01-01').diff(moment('1776-06-04')) < 0
```

So, looking at your code, try this out:

```
var lowerBound = moment('1776-06-04');
var dateField = $('#myDateField').val();

// String replace and put in proper format for moment
dateField = dateField.replace(/(\/)/g,'-');
var year = dateField.split('-')[2];
var month = dateField.split('-')[0];
var day = dateField.split('-')[1];

if (month < 10) { month = "0" + month; }
if (day < 10) { day = "0" + day; }
dateField = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

// Enter into moment and compare
var dateToConsider = moment(dateField);
var lowerLimitBreached = dateToConsider.diff(lowerBound) < 0;

if (lowerLimitBreached)
    $('form').submit();
```

Comment: "Since you're using moment, don't use the javascript Date object at all" --- you don't need momentjs to compare 2 dates.

Comment: Isn't that the OPs question, though?

Comment: It is. OP did not state anywhere a solution must be momentjs based specifically.

Comment: Needs to support IE 8.  I used my test year, 1/1/0001 and got `Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 EST 1901`.  If I used your test year of `0001-02-03`, `Date.parse` gives me `Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1903`, so it's treating the 3rd column like a year, instead of the day, for me.

Comment: @vapcguy "Needs to support IE 8" --- what is the reason that prevented you from putting it into the question? We cannot read your mind that you still support ancient browsers.

Comment: Relevance.  Moment supports IE 8, and using things like `Date.parse()` is vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Okay, it supports it - use it. It does not - file a bug.

Comment: This is close.  If I hard-code `dateField` as `0001-01-01` it works, so the rest is getting it to work with the input format.  It will come in as `1/1/0001`, so the rest is replacing the slashes (code needs 2 of those `.replace('/','-')` to make that work), and the rest is re-arranging the date so it's in the YYYY-MM-DD ISO format.  So this works -- thanks.

Comment: Edited the code above to show how I formatted it to use the moment lines - final solution. Oh, and I noticed that moment actually doesn't need the month subtracted-by-one, but forgot to edit that from 6 to 7 for the July, up there.

Comment: I noticed your edit as I had to approve it. I had a question about the `.replace('/','-').replace('/','-');` - why is it necessary to do this twice? I see you also said something about it in your previous comment above.

Comment: One time for each `/` character.  It doesn't do it throughout the string (I tried it).  To do that, I believe you need `\g` or something, but I was lazy and didn't look up the syntax.

Comment: Apparently I never did a string replace in javascript, but I found the regular expression approach for what you're doing. Given `var s = '1/1/0001';` this expression `s = s.replace(/(\/)/g,'-');` replaces all `/`.

Comment: Yep, that's the one... warts and all.  With all the slashes you might now understand why I initially went with my quick approach, lol.  Production code could benefit from the regex, though.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you do this?

```
var lowerBound = moment('1776-6-4');
var dateField = moment($('#myDateField').val());
var lowerLimitBreached = moment(lowerBound).isAfter(dateField);

if (!lowerLimitBreached)
    $('form').submit();
```

You're already using moment, just convert the kendo picker's date to a moment object and use `isAfter` or `isBefore`.

If this doesn't work, please provide a date that the picker might return that's not working for you

Comment: I think at this point the #myDateField value is 1/1/0001, so we need to do something about that problem. In moment or the Date constructor, both evaluate to 1901.

Comment: Moment will tell you if it couldn't parse the date. It might be that you need to include a format string in the second moment. What does the pickers value come back as

Comment: It parses it, that's not the problem - it does put it into a date format.  The problem is what ThisClark said.  `dateField` shows with the 1901 date. Picker will deliver M/D/YYYY or whatever the user inputs.  I was using `1/1/0001` for testing since that's what our testers were using.  Typically the control uses slashes if you pick from the calendar, but does allow typing (unfortunately).

Comment: So the real problem is that the picker is allowing an invalid date to be entered. So why don't you test against the 1901 date or set a min date to the picker?

Comment: Testing against 1901 says the value is true/allowed because the lower bound in my example is 1776, when the entered date, `1/1/0001`, is actually earlier than 1776.  The min date on the picker actually is 1/1/1900, but they have the ability to type anything.  So I have to set the min (which is actually lower than 1900) in the code.

Comment: Yes sorry I realized the 1901 was above your min date after I posted that